# Regex find all words start with two slashes

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I want to find all the characters that start with two slashes after `<body>` tag
example:-

```
http://www
// this is first comment
<body>
<div>
// this is comment
<p>//this is another comment.
```

so I want to match both:

```
// this is comment.
//this is another comment.
```

but not:

```
//www
// this is first comment
```

This is just example it might also contains digits and brackets. 
language php just want regex

Comment: @DavidThomas thanks so much i'm too much tired.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this PHP code:

```
$html = <<< EOF
http://www
// this is first comment
<body>
<div>
// this is comment
<p>//this is another comment.
EOF;
```

#### Solution 1: With negative lookahead

```
if (preg_match_all('~//(?!.*?<body>)[^\n]*~is', $html, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

#### Solution 2: Without lookaheads

```
$html = preg_replace('#^.*?<body>#is', '', $html);
if (preg_match_all('~//[^\n]*~', $html, $arr))
   print_r($arr);
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => // this is comment
            [1] => //this is another comment.
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this pattern:

```
(?<!http:)\/\/(\s?[\w\.])+
```

[example](http://regexr.com?31sfo)

Comment: well http is not in my consideration. I just give that for example.
so not not to match anything that is above body and has forwardslash

Comment: I guess you have to extract <body> node, and then search for comments using regular expressions, because using regular expression to do the 'after <body>' thing doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AdamWolski well there can be a method to ignore every thing before <body> tag and just select "//."

Comment: Yes, there is such a method, but it is actually like parsing HTML by regex. And it's bad!